# Error java.util.NoSuchElementException because I can't create Mock the restTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, resttemplate

I want do test a my service the Springboot but when my test arrive a restTemplate.getForObject crashes ...

Code test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ApplicationTestsCoverServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    MonitorServiceImpl monitorService;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    Mockito mk;

    @Test
    public void testGetOperativesMonitor() throws Exception {
        MonitorOperative operative[] = new MonitorOperative[1];
        operative[0] = new MonitorOperative();
        operative[0].setOperativeId("1A");

        this.mk.when(this.restTemplate.getForObject(
                Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(MonitorOperative[].class)))
                .thenReturn(operative);

        ResponseEntity<List<MonitorOperativeFront>> operative2 = monitorService.getOperativesMonitor("edu");
        assertEquals(operative[0].getOperativeId(), "1A");
    }
}
```

I am using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner for this.

I created a object "operative" for when my Mockito intercept the call the restTemplate return the object "operative" in my Implementation.

Finally launch `monitorService.getOperativesMonitor("edu");`

Now my test join in Implementation

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MonitorServiceImpl implements MonitorService {

@Value("${urlRest.urlBase}")
private String urlBase;
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

public ResponseEntity<List<MonitorOperativeFront>> getOperativesMonitor(String userCode) {

    log.info(" ---> LogInfo: start ");

    String url = this.urlBase + "/" + userCode);

    log.info(" ---> LogInfo: call to: " + url);
    List<MonitorOperativeFront> list= null ;
    try {
        MonitorOperative[] operative = this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, MonitorOperative[].class);
        list.add(new MonitorOperativeFront(operative[0].getId()));
        log.info(" ---> LogInfo: Success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

My code is easy, I created a url y then I use restTemplate, My app runs good, but when I use "CoverAs" with Junit, I get error in restTemplate:

Code error:

```
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:43.825 [main] ApplicationTests - Started ApplicationTests in 9.325 seconds (JVM running for 44.702)
[WARN ] 2019-08-14 13:19:43.827 [main] LoggingEnvironmentListener - ******************************************************
[WARN ] 2019-08-14 13:19:43.827 [main] LoggingEnvironmentListener - Kafka appenders are not in the configuration, so the system disables sending traces to Kafka
[WARN ] 2019-08-14 13:19:43.827 [main] LoggingEnvironmentListener - ******************************************************
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.436 [main]    MonitorServiceImpl -  ---> LogInfo: start
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.436 [main]    MonitorServiceImpl -  ---> LogInfo: call to: http:// secret
No value present
No value present
No value present
class java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at es.bank.darwin.security.authentication.converter.TokenConverter.lambda$getJwtToken$1(TokenConverter.java:55)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at es.bank.darwin.security.authentication.converter.TokenConverter.getJwtToken(TokenConverter.java:55)
    at es.bank.darwin.security.authentication.interceptor.JWTInterceptor.intercept(JWTInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at es.bank.darwin.omnichannel.interceptor.OmniChannelInterceptor.intercept(OmniChannelInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at es.bank.darwin.logging.http.LoggingHeadersInterceptor.intercept(LoggingHeadersInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at es.bank.darwin.common.interceptors.AppKeyInterceptor.intercept(AppKeyInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:296)
    at es.bank.mrpa.ServiceImpl.MonitorServiceImpl.getOperativesMonitor(MonitorServiceImpl.java:208)
    at es.bank.mrpa.ServiceImpl.MonitorServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e1f6dc2e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at es.bank.mrpa.ServiceImpl.MonitorServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$286bbf09.getOperativesMonitor(<generated>)
    at es.bank.mrpa.ApplicationTestsCoverServiceImpl.testGetOperativesMonitor(ApplicationTestsCoverServiceImpl.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.455 [Thread-10]    GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@1ecc1a99: startup date [Wed Aug 14 13:19:14 CEST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@729fc36a 
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.460 [Thread-10]    DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647 
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.461 [Thread-10]    DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483547 
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.461 [Thread-10]    DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 0 
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.462 [Thread-18]    GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@503b237e: startup date [Wed Aug 14 13:19:35 CEST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1c33043d 
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.501 [Thread-18]    DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647 
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.501 [Thread-18]    DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483547 
[INFO ] 2019-08-14 13:19:44.501 [Thread-18]    DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 0
```

I think that my

```
  this.mk.when(this.restTemplate.getForObject(
                Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(MonitorOperative[].class)))
                .thenReturn(operative);
```

Doesn't run, because my test-Implementation try to call restTemplate...

Comment: The problem is that, when you autowire `MonitorServiceImpl`, its created by Spring and the real `RestTemplate` is injected. Try instead of autowiring `MonitorServiceImpl`, mark it with `@InjectMocks` annotation, or create `MonitorServiceImpl` constructor, which accepts `RestTemplate` and create `MonitorServiceImpl`  manually and pass mocked one in the test.

Comment: If I change  Autowired for InjectMocks the MonitorServiceImpl, the test fail because "this.urlBase" is null

Comment: how can I created my service with restTemplate in the construct ??? also I should be send params as this.urlBase. thanks

Comment: Ok, you can create constructor:   
`public MonitorServiceImpl(@Value("${urlRest.urlBase}") String urlBase,  
                                           @Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate) {  
        this.urlBase = urlBase;  
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;  
}  `

You can omit @Autowired in constructor depending on the Spring version.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Comment: And in test add setup method
`@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
   monitorService = new MonitorServiceImpl("anyUrl", fakeRestTemplate);
}
`

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov: Why don't you add an answer for this question? I find code in the comments always hard to read.

Comment: thanks guys, Finally I can resolve this :))